# Best Option for converting & processing multiple analog data lines

Tags: microcontroller, analog, microchip, microprocessor

I am looking for a good Microcontroller (or DSP or other device if they are more applicable) option that has a reasonably large amount of analog input data lines (preferably > 10 analog input lines) and an on-chip ADC.  The clock speed shoudl probably also be equal to or greater than 1 MHz.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How fast are you sampling?

Comment: What are the characteristics of the signals?

Answer (score 1):

A good option would be something like the [dsPIC33FJ64GP802](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en532310#documentation), or one of it's family. This particular one has up to 13 analog inputs and can do 4-channels simultaneously (it has 4 Sample and Holds) It can sample up to 1.1Msps. It also has 8-ch DMA which takes the load from the CPU and makes things very fast if used correctly.
Here is the [ADC part](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70183D.pdf) of the Family Reference Manual which will tell you a lot more.

Instruction clock speed-wise, it can go up to 40 MIPS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this selected list](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?FV=fff40027%2Cfff800cd%2C81c001c%2C81c001e%2C81c001f%2C81c0020%2C81c0021%2C81c0022%2C81c0023%2C81c0024%2C81c0025%2C81c0028%2C81c0029%2C81c002a%2C81c002c%2C81c002e%2C81c0030%2C81c003a%2C81c003b%2C81c003d%2C81c003e%2C81c0040%2C81c0045%2C81c0046%2C81c007e%2C81c0080%2C81c0088%2C81c008d%2C81c008e%2C81c0090%2C81c0092%2C81c009a%2C81c009b%2C81c009c%2C81c009d%2C81c00a3%2C81c00af%2C81c00b0%2C81c00b7%2C81c00bf%2C81c00c5%2C81c00c9%2C81c00ca%2C81c00cb%2C81c00cc%2C81c00cd%2C81c00d2%2C81c00dc%2C81c00dd%2C81c00de%2C81c00df%2C81c00e0%2C81c00e1%2C81c00e3%2C81c00e8%2C81c00e9%2C81c00ec%2C81c00ee%2C81c00ef%2C81c00f0%2C81c0102%2C81c0107%2C81c0108%2C81c0109%2C81c010a%2C81c010b%2C81c010c%2C81c0111%2C81c0115%2C81c0116%2C81c0117%2C81c0118%2C81c0119%2C81c011c%2C81c011e%2C81c0123%2C81c0127%2C81c0129%2C81c012e%2C81c0130%2C81c0131%2C81c0132%2C81c0134%2C81c0135%2C81c0136%2C81c0137%2C81c0139%2C81c0144%2C81c0146%2C81c0147%2C81c0148%2C81c0149%2C81c014a%2C81c014b%2C81c014d%2C81c0151%2C81c0154%2C81c0156%2C81c0159%2C81c015a%2C81c015b%2C81c0161%2C81c0163%2C81c0164%2C81c0165%2C81c0168%2C81c0169%2C81c016d%2C81c0173%2C81c0175%2C81c0176%2C81c0177%2C81c017c%2C81c017d%2C81c017e%2C81c017f%2C81c0180%2C81c0181%2C81c0182%2C81c0183%2C81c0184%2C81c0185%2C81c0186%2C81c0187%2C81c0189%2C81c018b%2C81c018c%2C81c0192%2C81c0193%2C81c0194%2C81c0195%2C81c019d%2C81c01a0%2C81c01a3%2C81c01a4%2C81c01a9%2C81c01aa%2C81c01ab%2C81c01ac%2C81c01ad%2C81c01ae%2C81c01af%2C81c01b0%2C81c01b1%2C81c01b2%2C81c01b3%2C81c01b6%2C81c01b7%2C81c01b8%2C81c01bc%2C81c01bd%2C81c01be%2C81c01bf&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=-519&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0) from DigiKey, sorted in decreasing order of data converter channels on the chip.